# What type of system is more stable?

Tags: energy

Between two systems of unequal amount of energy, which one is more stable? The one with higher energy or the one with lower energy and why?I think the lower energy system is more stable but i do not know why.

Comment: Energy has to be measured with respect to something to have physical meaning, so this is not a well-posed question. But even so, energy *difference* alone is not enough to say which state is most stable. Typically, larger energy differences are associated with larger activation energies and therefore slower transition rates (and therefore increase stability) but this is not always true.

Answer (score 1):

The stability of a system does not depend on its absolute energy (or the relative energy differences between two instances of this system) but on the local form of the energy-landscape plotted over the variables. A system is in an unstable equilibrium if it is in an energy maximum (imagine a harmonic oscillator at an angle of $\varphi=\pi$ - the system does not move, but it is instable in that it will immediately move far away from this point if it is disturbed). It is in a stable equilibrium if it is in a local energy minimum and it will in general be expected to move if it is in neither. This is a very simplified description though - kinetic effects can cause a lot of differences (e.g. "frozen states" which move so slowly that they are effectively stable on the time scale of any observation) and if there are thermal fluctuations, neither a local minimum nor a maximum are completely stable as the fluctuations can always drive the system into another local minimum.